# Get the package Name of current app which is in foreground from the service of different application which is in background?

Tags: android

I need to find the package Name of the application which is running in foreground by the broadcast Receiver class of another application which is in background. So when a new application comes to foreground I need to get the package Name from the broadcast receiver which is inter a class of different application.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Nothing is triggered when app is in foreground (Here app will be any other app, which different from the app which as the code). And finally I need to get the package name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a service in the background app, this service will run an endless thread which will check every one second for the current app, prior lollipop you will use this code,

mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();